# How to make a slider stop when video is playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this website which has a slider in the middle of the page. I put a video in the slider but the problem is when I play the video I need the slider to stop its effect so the video can play. Any ideas how to make this happen.

Here is the website it is on.

http://flamingoroadchurch.com.previewdns.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener to that video somehow. Have you looked at Vimeo's js api?

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/moogaloop

You may want to take a close look at that js_onLoad function.

**p.s.**: You might get better answers around here if you accepted one. You do this by clicking the little check mark next to an answer.